# Vs Code C++ Quickly Switching Multiple Gcc, msVs Compiler Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, visual-c++, version

How did I do it in 'olden days'
I started with Visual Studio C++ but complicated setting made legal and standard, and their conversion of code to updated version of visual studio scared me off intellectually and dummed me up to low of the lowest so I escaped to Code Blocks and 'Bucky' videos. There, I installed newest gcc version and run newest code well. But, when I run older code, it did not run. So, I downloaded few gcc versions, created directories next to Code Blocks'es default compiler directory and renamed an old version of gcc to Code Blocks gcc-setup dir. It bore fruits, now the old code run well with a little trial and errror and little time lost by just renaming one directory. Also, names were like gcc1,gcc2,...gccn, for quick renaming and more focus on code than settings.

--VS CODE SETUP FOR MULTI C++ COMPILERS CONFIGURATIONS--

Vs code is wonderfull and I do hope it remains a wonderfull ide.

The Question-for Vs Code C++ multi compiler switch
Analog to my Code Blocks mainpulation of gcc physical-directories, is there a possibility to make a switch for example for gcc versions(2010,2015,2022) and msvs versions(2010,2015,2022) when oppening cpp files. If yes, how?
If no, could You please make a compact list of all settings for gcc and compact list of all msvs settings so I can coin-up something simple with powershell,
for example, I think replacing c++ jsons instead of creating 6 Vs Code physical copies for each c++ compiler version. Say we I run ps-gui, choose from 6 options which replaces physical Vs Code c++ compiler json settings-file to version I choose in the gui, and then it opens c++ file inside Vs Code with choosen version of compiler?

Why I mentioned 6 instances of Vs code. For example, I installed powershell with many many nice and usefull extensions. After that, When I type, Ps code intellisense is messed up. It either happens nothing or it shows suggestions after a minute or so. It got it's own mood. So I have several Vs code instances each for their own group of extensions that communicate well. This way is much easier to catch when one extension stopps working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use CMake and the CMake Tools extension for VS Code. Then you can generate buildsystems for each of your compiler toolchains. If you want easy switching between them, you can define [a preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for each one.

Comment: I have not time for cMake now. Could You give me a 10y old example or pointers to Yt-videos/webs for say we 4 configurations, say we again, two for Msvc and another two for Gcc, and how 'switching' is done. For example, for Visual Studio switches a project solution/project file by just R-clicking and selecting version to open solution or project with. How cMake can compile with my versions of downloaded gcc versions and installed versions of Visual Studio. As far as I see cMake offers not all versions of gcc or Msvc, just preConfigured ones. YT-video/web-page would be nice.

Comment: @ConfidentlyErrored if you use [kits](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/kits.md), CMake Tools can detect what compilers you have installed. I'd recommend to use [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) though.

Comment: Not helpful, but thanks for trying.